# Understanding recursive triangle number function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, math

I have the following recursive function that returns the nth triangle number. Could you explain how the output is, for example, `10` when I run `how(4)`?

```
def how(n):
   if(n==1):
      return 1;
   else:
      return(n+how(n-1))
print(how(4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function logic is as follows - if `n` is `1`, return `1`. Otherwise, return `n + how(n-1)`. If we step through the function for `how(4)`, we can see how this might work:

```
how(4) - returns 4 + how(3)
how(3) - returns 3 + how(2)
how(2) - returns 2 + how(1)
how(1) - returns 1
```

Putting all this together, the following are equivalent:

```
how(4) - returns 4 + how(3)
how(4) - returns 4 + 3 + how(2)
how(4) - returns 4 + 3 + 2 + how(1)
how(4) - returns 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
```